# Convert date en letter into numeric and sort

Tags: r, date, sorting

I have such format of date (date in factor format) in my dataframe, I would like to sort

```
date<-factor (c("13DEC2016", "02JAN2016", "27APR2016"))
```

The objective is to sort it in order to have something like:

```
02JAN2016 27APR2016 13DEC2016
```

or like:

```
02-01-2016  27-04-2016  13-12-2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the date you need to first change the class of `date` from factor to date. This can be done using base R or `lubridate` package.

```
date<-factor (c("13DEC2016", "02JAN2016", "27APR2016"))
#Using base R
sorted_date <- sort(as.Date(date, '%d%b%Y'))
sorted_date
#[1] "2016-01-02" "2016-04-27" "2016-12-13"
#Using `lubridate`
sorted_date <- sort(lubridate::dmy(date))
```

Once you do that you can use `format` to get data in whichever format you want.

```
format(sorted_date, '%d-%b-%Y')
#[1] "02-Jan-2016" "27-Apr-2016" "13-Dec-2016"
format(sorted_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
#[1] "02-01-2016" "27-04-2016" "13-12-2016"
toupper(format(sorted_date, '%d%b%Y'))
#[1] "02JAN2016" "27APR2016" "13DEC2016"
```

Comment: ```as.Date(date, '%d%b%Y')``` gave me ```NA NA NA```

Comment: `%b` is locale dependent. You should have locale as English for R to identify `DEC`, `JAN` etc as month names.